# Cannot access function through this

Tags: javascript, this

I was trying to figure out how this works and I tried a few things. But I keep on getting an a TypeError which clearly means that I have not assigned the this variable correctly. Would be great if someone could point out where am I going wrong, and if the way I am using is correct or not.

So,

I have a main file, service.js

```
class Service {
  constructor() {
    const cronService = new (require('./cron.js'))(this);
    cronService.start();
    this.newService = new (require('./newService.js'))(this);
  }
}

const x = new Service();
```

This accesses two other files,

newService.js

```
class NewService {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
    this.logger = this.service.logger;
    this.system = this.service.system;
  }

  async function1() {
    console.log('woohoo');
  }
}
module.exports = NewService;
```

and cron.js

```
class CronService {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  async start() {
    await this.f2();
  }

  async f2() {
    const self = this;
    self.service.function1();
  } 
}
module.exports = CronService;
```

When I run node service.js, I expect a console log of woohoo. But I keep on getting an error, that `self.service.function1` is not a function.

I have tried many combinations like self.function1, this.function1, this.service.newService.function1 but all of them either result in the above TypeError or it leading to be undefined.

How to look at this issue? What am I doing wrong? I know I could directly import newService.js but I was looking to learn if I could call function1 from cron.js without importing it into cron.js.
Thanks

Comment: Isn't it a problem that you **require** CronService before NewService?

Comment: what are you expecting this: `new (require('./cron.js'))(this);` to do? the require code should probably go at the top of you'r file

Comment: Just a small note about the semantics in your question: `this` is not a variable in javascript but a protected keyword, and cannot be assigned (at least not as a variable can be assigned)

Comment: As per your code You have passed this to the `new CronServeice` instance,  so self.service in CronService will point to **Service this** , not to NewService this..

Comment: The class `Service` doesn't have a declared function called `function1`

Comment: I've tried adding newService before cron.js too but it still does not work.

Comment: @KCFragrance is there anyway to make it to point to newService this from Service this?

Comment: Try after passing `this.NewService `to CronService instance instead of this

Comment: Hmm @KCFragrance still does not work :(

Comment: Like `  this.newService = new (require('./newService.js'))(this);                             
    const cronService = new (require('./cron.js'))(this.newService);
    cronService.start();`

Answer (score 1):

According to the logic in the code you've posted, probably what you really want is passing `this.newService` as param in `new CronService(this.newService)`.

```js
class NewService {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
    this.logger = this.service.logger;
    this.system = this.service.system;
  }

  function1() {
    console.log('woohoo');
  }
}
//module.exports = NewService;

class CronService {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  start() {
    this.f2();
  }

  f2() {
    const self = this;
    self.service.function1();
  }
}
//module.exports = CronService;

class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.newService = new NewService(this);
    const cronService = new CronService(this.newService);
    cronService.start();
  }
}

const x = new Service();
```